# Ajax calls in an interval slows down map

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am building a tracking app that takes locations from a database that is updated frequently and put the last updated data as the marker..I use a ajax call in an interval that is called in every second to retrieve live updating data..

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async:false,
     dataType: "json",
     url: "{{ url('/tracking_mysql/bt6pmSWHTfnOAjfJMlSvRQ==') }}",
     success: function(data)
     {
      @foreach($eventUsers as $eventUser)
        markers['marker' + '{{$eventUser->userId}}'] = null ;
      @endforeach
      $.each(data,function(u,v){
      markers['marker' + v['user_id']] = new google.maps.LatLng(v['Location'].split(' ')[0],v['Location'].split(' ')[1]);
     lastUpdatedTimes['lastUpdatedTime' + v['user_id']] = v['time'];
   });
  }
});
```

and the controller that passes the current locations is :

```
 public function get_locations($eventid)
    {
            $eventId = $event_group_Idarray[0];
            $locations = DB::table('locations')
                ->select('time', 'Location','user_id')
                ->join(DB::raw('( SELECT MAX(id) as Id FROM locations GROUP BY user_id ) AS newest'), function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('locations.id', '=', 'newest.id');
                })
                ->where('event_id',$eventId)
                ->get();

            print_r(json_encode($locations));
    }
```

the problem is during each ajax call the map updation freezes for a moment.I am sure the problem is using ajax calls in an interval..I commented the ajax call and passed random markers in an interval,the map was smooth..is there any solution that can be used for my purpose ?

Comment: How many markers are you updating every second?  How big is the data returned by the server (how long does the transfer take)?  How long does it take to process that response?  Probably the processing is taking all or most of the second between requests, either slow down the requests or make the processing more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using synchronous Ajax call.
Try Asynchronous Ajax call.

```js
var jqAjax = null;

function updateMap() {
 //this will abort old pending request
 jqAjax && jqAjax.abort();
 
 jqAjax = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "{{ url('/tracking_mysql/bt6pmSWHTfnOAjfJMlSvRQ==') }}",
  success: function(data) {@
   foreach($eventUsers as $eventUser)
   markers['marker' + '{{$eventUser->userId}}'] = null;@
   endforeach
   $.each(data, function(u, v) {
    markers['marker' + v['user_id']] = new google.maps.LatLng(v['Location'].split(' ')[0], v['Location'].split(' ')[1]);
    lastUpdatedTimes['lastUpdatedTime' + v['user_id']] = v['time'];
   });
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi one thing that i would like to suggest that use **"cache: true"** parameter with the Ajax call that may reduce some performance issue (it will not reduce completely but help to reduce).

Comment: As described in the [$.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `cache: true` is the default for `dataType: 'json'`, so this will have no effect. The real problem is the `async: false` as SNT93's answer points out.

Comment: Thanx dude for informing back to me